# How can I link a JavaScript variable to a HTML value?

Tags: javascript, html, variables

I need to link an item in a table to a Javascript variable, but it won't link. I think there will be further problems changing the value.

I am running on Atom Editor, with the script package installed, although I could copy the script into Notepad++ or Brackets if needed.

```
</tr>
    <td>Abena</td>
    <td>Natale</td>
    <td id = "Abena_Natale">11782</td>
    <td>No.1</td>
    <td>Monarch of Boars</td>
</tr>

<script>
var Abena_Natale = ""

</script>
```

I expected to get a variable that would change the value in the Abena_Natale element when the Javascript stated. Instead, it just stays the same.

Comment: We appreciate that you're a beginner, but you seem to have some considerable assumptions about functionality which doesn't exist without the use of complex frameworks.  It's recommended that you start with some introductory tutorials on JavaScript, including how to write to the HTML elements (often called the DOM) or read values from HTML elements.  Simply declaring a variable doesn't create a bi-directional binding, or any relationship whatsoever, with HTML elements.

Comment: `var Abena_Natale = ""` by using `var` this code create a new variable.

Comment: Agree with @David, recommend doing so good tutorials on build the HTML, get that solid first. Will help you immensely as you move forward.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was an error in your HTML.
From there we need to write the selector to get the element.
And then grab the content inside the node.

Update to support editing.

```js
var Abena_Natale = "";
var abenaElement;

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  abenaElement = document.querySelector('#Abena_Natale');
  Abena_Natale = abenaElement.innerHTML;

  console.log(Abena_Natale);
  
  // Update the value
  abenaElement.innerHTML = "Testing";
  
});
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Abena</td>
    <td>Natale</td>
    <td id="Abena_Natale">11782</td>
    <td>No.1</td>
    <td>Monarch of Boars</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

That's not how you access the [Document Object Model (DOM)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_Object_Model/Introduction) with JS. You need to grab the element using one from a number of methods, and *then* amend the data.

1) Make sure your table row elements are opened and closed correctly.

2) Use either [`document.getElementById('Abena_Natale')`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById), or [`document.querySelector('#Abena_Natale')`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) to grab the element.

3) Set the [`textContent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pl/docs/Web/API/Element/textContent) of the element. `value` is generally used for `input` elements.

```js
const aN = document.getElementById('Abena_Natale');
aN.textContent = 'This has been changed';
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Abena</td>
    <td>Natale</td>
    <td id="Abena_Natale">11782</td>
    <td>No.1</td>
    <td>Monarch of Boars</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```